# JFrog artifactory search API based on path after repos parameter

Tags: artifactory

I'm using Jfrog Artifactory to store my build artifacts of maven type, I've setup repository as `$ARTIFACT_BASEURL/MYREPO/TeamName/API_Name/api-1.0.0.jar`, where `MYREPO` is the actual repository name and `TeamName/API_Name` is subfolder in it to store api specific artifacts. All good while I do API build and push the artifacts to their respective folders in `MYREPO`.

While I try to lookup at the repository using JFrog search API, it is not allowing subfolder/path in the search API, like I mentioned below,

Currently: `curl -H X-JFrog-Art-Api:apikey “https://artifactory.company.com/artifactory/api/search/artifact?name=company&repos=MYREPO”`

Expected: `Curl -H X-JFrog-Art-Api:apikey “https://artifactory.company.com/artifactory/api/search/artifact?name=company&repos=MYREPO/TeamName/API_Name”`
or:
`Curl -H X-JFrog-Art-Api:apikey “https://artifactory.company.com/artifactory/api/search/artifact?name=company&repos=MYREPO&path=TeamName/API_Name”`

so that I can do a lookup on the binaries stored in this path.

Please suggest/correct me in getting the process right

Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mentioned that you are using Artifactory to store Maven artifacts. The current layout you are applying for your artifacts is not a standard Maven2 [reposiotry layout](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVENOLD/Repository+Layout+-+Final). when using Maven typed repositories, Artifactory relies on having a correct layout and therefore the Artifactory search API will not be able to find your artifacts.
You are currently trying to use the quick search API, which only allow searching by artifact name. There are other types of search methods, for example the [GAVC search](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-GAVCSearch) which allows you to also search by the Maven groupId and version.
There are a couple of options:

(1) Conform to standard Maven [repository layout](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVENOLD/Repository+Layout+-+Final) and use [GAVC search](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-GAVCSearch)
(2) Work with a [generic](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Repositories#ConfiguringRepositories-GenericRepositories) Artifactory repository and apply a [custom layout](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Layouts) which matches the current layout you are using. This will allow you to search for artifacts while keeping the current layout you are using.
(3) Keep your current setup and you the [Artifactory Query Language](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Query+Language) (AQL) to [search](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactoryQueryLanguage(AQL)) for artifacts based on path, for example:

```
items.find({"repo": "myrepo"}, {"path" : "a/b/c"})
```